Condition for Zero Eigenvalue in Sum of Two Random Hermitian Matrices
Let $a$ and $b$ be two independent complex Gaussian random matrices of size $N \times M$, with $M\geq N$.
Define two matrices $A = a^\dagger a$ and $B = b^\dagger b$ (so $A$ and $B$ are both Hermitian matrices of rank $N$).
Numerically, I find that the sum $A + B$ has a zero eigenvalue when $M \approx 2N$. When adding $P$ such hermitian matrices, I also find that a zero eigenvalue exists when $M \approx PN$. How to prove this?
It feels like there should be simple proof for this. One way would be to show that the sum is rank deficient, but I am unsure of how to infer the rank of the sum.

Take two random subspaces $U,V$ of dimension $M-N$ in $\mathbb R^M$, chosen with an uniform distribution.
You are trying to compute the probability that the intersection between $U,V$ is not trivial. This is easily proven to be 1 when $M-N>M/2$.

To be clear $A+B$ is singular when $ker(A)$ and $ker(B)$ intersect, but their dimension is $M-N$, so the dimension of their intersection is at least $2(M-N)-M = M-2N$
